# HLSL / GLSL High precision sqrt is feasible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, sqrt

A sonogram post-processing Math.Sqrt() is high-quality and slow in CPU. It's fast and low quality on GFX card, using HLSL, on Unity game engine. it looks like 12 bit, presumably it's 16 bit.

Is there a way to do a precise **sqrt()** approximation / equivalent on the GFX card?

[image]

Here is the code, it's HLSL

```
        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {

            float4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);         
            c = sqrt(c);
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;          

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your shader code:

```
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_nicest
```